# How can I Junit test reading a file then storing the content to an ArrayList

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to create junit test to see if the content inside a File is added into an arraylist

Here is my function:

```
    public List readContent(final File file, final boolean isFirstFile) throws IOException
    {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String strLine;
            if (!isFirstFile)
            {
                br.readLine();
            }
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.add(strLine);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            LOG.info("An error occurred while reading file.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lines;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally: Separate the "open the file" step from the "read from the file" step: `public Reader openFile(File file)`, `public List<String> readContent(Reader r)`. (And don't ever ignore compiler warnings, like the "raw types" warning you're getting.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JUnit temporary file. It basically creates a file/folder for you during the test and when the test finishes it will be deleted.

To test it you just create that file, put the data you want on it and then call your method. Then you assert result of the method with the value you were expecting.

About the temporary file for JUnit 4: https://howtodoinjava.com/junit/junit-creating-temporary-filefolder-using-temporaryfolder-rule/

In case you using JUnit 5: https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-temporary-directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TemporaryFolder` to create temporary folders and files and ErrorCollector to assert more one assertion

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TargetTest {

    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    @Rule
    public RuleChain chain = RuleChain.outerRule(collector).around(folder);

    private TargetClass target;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        target = new TargetClass();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReadFile() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        File file = folder.newFile("myfile.txt");

        // Act
        List actual = target.readContent(file, true);

        // Assert
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply create a test file (or several depending on what you want to test) that you would store in the `src/test/resources` folder (if you use Maven/Gradle) and then as part of your test preparation you would load this file and pass it to the method.